# Providing input for multiple read(stdin) calls via bash input redirection

Tags: io-redirection, read, input

Suppose we have the following program, which calls `read()` twice:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SIZE 0x100

int main(void)
{
    char buffer1[SIZE];
    char buffer2[SIZE];

    printf("Enter first input: \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer1, SIZE);

    printf("Enter second input: \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer2, SIZE);

    printf("\nFirst input:\n%s", buffer1);
    printf("\nSecond input:\n%s", buffer2);

    return 0;
}
```

When we call it directly, we can enter `1` for the first input and `2` for the second input in order to have it print:

```
First input:
1

Second input:
2
```

How can this be achieved when using input redirection?

The following methods don't work, since the first `read` consumes both inputs:

Pipe redirection:

```
$ { echo "1"; echo "2"; } | ./main_read
Enter first input:
Enter second input:

First input:
1
2

Second input:
```

Heredoc redirection:

```
$ ./main_read << EOF
1
2
EOF
Enter first input:
Enter second input:

First input:
1
2

Second input:
```

The assumption is that the source code cannot be changed, and that the input must sometimes be shorter than `SIZE`.

Is there any way to signal the first `read()` to stop reading, in order for the second `read()` to consume the rest of the input?

Comment: Thanks, I've already visited this page, and I've reviewed it again now. If it contains an obvious answer to my question, I must be missing it. Can you please point me to the section I should be concentrating on?

Comment: What do you mean by "the input must sometimes be shorter than `SIZE`"? (Maybe it's just me, but I'm unable to parse "must sometimes" in this context).

Comment: @Quasímodo - no problem, thanks anyway.

Comment: @fra-san - I mean, providing 0x100 bytes as the first input in order to max-out the first  `read()` isn't an acceptable solution.

Comment: Not even padding the actual input with NUL bytes?

Comment: @fra-san - Unfortunately not, looking for a solution which causes the read to stop reading before hitting the max buffer size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely not to provide an acceptable solution to you, but considering that:

- > the source code cannot be changed
- the shell can not change where the open file descriptors of a running program point to, nor make a running program stop reading from a file descriptor

Some alternatives you are left with (short of exploiting a race condition) are:

- Trying to make sure your program is always fed with `SIZE` bytes at a time:

  ```bsh
  {
    echo foo | dd bs=256 conv=sync
    echo bar | dd bs=256 conv=sync
  } 2>/dev/null | ./main_read
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  Enter first input: 
  Enter second input: 

  First input:
  foo

  Second input:
  bar
  ```

  This assumes, as a minimum, that `SIZE` is smaller than the size of the pipe buffer.
- Wrapping the invocation of your program in an `expect` (or equivalent) script:

  ```bsh
  expect <<'EOT'
  spawn ./main_read
  expect "Enter first input:"
  send "foo\n"
  expect "Enter second input:"
  send "bar\n"
  expect eof
  EOT
  ```

  Or, in a way that allows you to pipe to it the output of other commands, read separately (assuming your operating system provides processes with the `/dev/fd/n` file descriptors):

  ```bsh
  echo foo | {
    echo bar |
      expect 4<&0 <<'EOT'
      spawn ./main_read
      set chan [open "/dev/fd/3"]
      gets $chan line
      expect "Enter first input:"
      send "$line\r"
      close $chan
      set chan [open "/dev/fd/4"]
      gets $chan line
      expect "Enter second input:"
      send "$line\r"
      close $chan
      expect eof
  EOT
  } 3<&0
  ```

  In both cases, the output is:

  ```
  spawn ./main_read
  Enter first input: 
  foo
  Enter second input: 
  bar

  First input:
  foo

  Second input:
  bar
  ```
- On systems (such as Linux) that allow for opening pipes in a non-blocking fashion, you may use FIFOs to make the shell read from and write to your program. For instance:

  ```bsh
  makefifo fifo
  {
    exec 3<>fifo
    ./main_read 0<&3
  } |
  sh -c '
    # read a line from the pipe
    # read from a file or a different pipe, write to fifo
    # repeat ...
    # echo the output from the pipe
  ' mysh
  ```

  Though, if `expect` is available to you, I see no compelling reason to prefer reinventing it.

Note that, however, as others have pointed out, *there is no guarantee* that all of your program's `read`s will actually get `SIZE` bytes.

Comment: @Dvd848 I edited my answer substantially after initially posting it -- just a ping, I think question askers are not notified when answers are edited.

Comment: Thanks! For what it's worth, I think the example you edited out was worth keeping too, it's not as flexible as the other examples but is probably what I'd go for in cases where the extra flexibility isn't needed.

Comment: @Dvd848 Thank you for your feedback, I added that example back.

Answer (score 2):

> The assumption is that the source code cannot be changed

You should work primarily on changing that assumption.

There are in general no guarantees about how many bytes a `read()` call returns When reading from a regular file, it usually returns as many bytes as requested (up to how much are available), but that might not be the case for all types of file descriptors. Scheduling between the processes running on the system, and other such timing issues may also affect how much data is available with one call.

Doing a single `read()` call without checking the amount of data read is simply almost always wrong. Even cases like `dd` (which is explicitly supposed to expose the behaviour of the `read()` calls) and reading from datagram sockets (where a each individual `read()` gives a single message) will need the program to know how much data it got.

If the program is supposed to read lines, it should use `fgets()` or `getline()` and not raw `read()`. If it's supposed to read other sorts of blocks, it should implement some other way to tell the blocks apart. That could be either prepending them with a length, or using separate file descriptors, or using some delimiter (like newline, but it could be longer than just one byte).

That is, unless you arrange `stdin` to be connected to a datagram socket, but that would be a very unusual setup, and you couldn't really use regular input redirection to provide the data.

Also, before passing the buffers to `printf("%s")`, the program should make sure they contain the NUL bytes terminating the strings. As it is now, the program produces undefined behaviour if the data provided by either `read()` does not contain the NUL, including the case where the second `read()` returns no data at all.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to create a simple reference code to demonstrate the problem and using strings seemed like the simplest way to go. This is also the reason for skipping the different mandatory checks. In retrospective I regret this, I should have probably provided the missing checks/error handling as well.

Comment: @Dvd848, yes, well. It's a bit unclear what you're actually aiming to do. I mean, do you have some actual existing application that does reads like that, or are you just asking out of academic interest? If it's an existing application, then it would help to know which one it is, since it would probably have some other way to do that. If you're asking just out of curiosity, then yeah, datagram sockets are one thing that definitely keep message boundaries intact. Most stuff just works like streams of bytes with the structure built on the application level.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments below you could do:

```
{ echo a & sleep 0.1; echo b; } | ./main
```

Notice that you may have to adjust amount of time to sleep. The point of
this command is to make the first invocation of read() think that `a`
is the entire input it got. The *assumption* is that the C program
will reach the second read() after `echo a &` (note the `&` - it's
sent to the background) has already finished and was processed by the
first read(). But since Linux is a multi-user true multitasking OS
which additionally performs lazy virtual memory allocation `sleep 0.1`
may not be enough in all cases for this assumption to work.

The reason it works and

```
{ echo a && echo b; } | ./main
```

doses not is that read() reads the entire available stdin up to SIZE
characters the first time it's read, leaving no character to be read
for the second time. If you checked the value read() returns:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SIZE 0x100

int main(void)
{
    char buffer1[SIZE];
    char buffer2[SIZE];

    printf("Enter first line of input: \n");

    ssize_t read_bytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer1, SIZE);
    buffer1[read_bytes] = '\0';
    printf("First input - count of read bytes: %jd\n", (intmax_t) read_bytes);

    printf("Enter second line of input: \n");

    read_bytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer2, SIZE);
    printf("Second input - count of read bytes: %jd\n", (intmax_t) read_bytes);
    buffer2[read_bytes] = '\0';

    printf("\nFirst input:\n%s", buffer1);
    printf("\nSecond input:\n%s", buffer2);

    return 0;
}
```

you'd see that it doesn't read any character the second time:

```
$ ./main << EOF
1
2
EOF
Enter first line of input:
First input - count of read bytes: 4

First input:
1
2
Enter second line of input:
Second input - count of read bytes: 0

Second input:

First input:
1
2

Second input:
```

To make `{ echo a && echo b; } | ./main` work you'd have to either switch to
getline() or save both inputs to a single buffer and use strtok() to parse the buffer by newlines. getline()
version could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t size = 0x100;
    char *buffer1 = malloc(size);
    if (buffer1 == NULL)
        {
            perror("malloc");
        }


    char *buffer2 = malloc(size);
    if (buffer2 == NULL)
        {
            perror("malloc");
        }

    printf("Enter first line of input: \n");
    getline(&buffer1, &size, stdin);

    printf("Enter second line of input: \n");
    getline(&buffer2, &size, stdin);

    printf("\nFirst input:\n%s", buffer1);
    printf("\nSecond input:\n%s", buffer2);

    free(buffer1);
    free(buffer2);

    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
$ ./main << EOF
1
2
EOF
Enter first line of input:
Enter second line of input:

First input:
1

Second input:
2
```

There are 3 more points I'd like to discuss here:

- you don't need `fflush(stdout);` because stdout is
  always flushed after a newline
- you don't need to lookup for man pages on the Internet because you
  have them locally - just type `man 2 read` in the terminal or open
  them inside your editor (Emacs for example can do that)
- you have a bug in the code you posted in your question - `read()`
  does not add nul bytes automatically, you have to do it yourself to
  avoid UB. It should be:

  ```
    printf("Enter first line of input: \n");
    ssize_t read_bytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer1, SIZE - 1);
    buffer1[read_bytes] = '\0';
  ```

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - Thanks, I agree with your recommendation that using a different function instead of `read` would be better, but the assumption is that the code cannot be changed.

Comment: But you have to change it if you want it to behave differently.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - I tried to create a simplified reference code for the problem (also the reason for skipping error checking, NULL byte addition etc.), I don't control the actual program sources.

Comment: @Dvd848: ok, in that case Quasímodo's solution will work better for you, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: `{ echo a & sleep 0.1; echo b; } | ./main` only works if `./main` is scheduled between the two writes by the left-hand `echo`'s. That's not guaranteed, and might not be the case on a heavily-loaded system.

Comment: `buffer1[read_bytes] = '\0';` is also UB if `read_bytes` is the same as the allocated length of the array. You'd need to pass `SIZE - 1` as the count to `read()`, or allocate `SIZE+1` bytes in the arrays to account for the NUL.

Comment: @ilkkachu: both problems fixed (I'd like everyone to read my posts so carefully!)